# Send string that contains HTML to WebAPI post action

Tags: c#, http, encoding, tinymce, asp.net-core-webapi

I am struggling with some silly issue and I hope some of you guys has already encountered or has experience with something similar and will be able to help me out on this one.

I am using TinyMCE text editor in my app. And the content it generates is actually plain HTML.

So, I need to send that HTML via HTTP Post to my .net Core WebApi action.
When the html content is sent as it is, the .net framework is casting some of things(which makes sense). i.e. &nbsp is casted into \n, "(double quotes) are casted into \" and so on..

My question is, what is the best preferable way to encode (or somehow parse/escape) the html before it is sent so I can decode it on the server side and get the html the way it actually is?

Or maybe there is some c# library or attribute on the server side that will "uncast" the html to the original format that it was before it was sent over HTTP Post?

How the HTML looks on the client side before it is send on the server:

```
<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p><p>&nbsp;</p><h1>This is header</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span style="background-color: #f1c40f;">This is colored&nbsp;</span></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: center;">This is centered&nbsp;</p>
```

And how it looks when it is received on the server side:

```
<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<h1>This is header</h1>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p><span style=\"background-color: #f1c40f;\">This is colored&nbsp;</span></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\">This is centered&nbsp;</p>
```

It is adding \n before each   and it is also escaping the double quotes. I interested in how can this be avoided?

Cheers.

Comment: How do you know the content is being changed by the client? Maybe it is being changed on the server side. It would help if you posted your code and showed some examples of the text before and after.

Comment: You could use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode() and then System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() within the API?

Comment: @Jim Rodes, I've updated my question with examples on how it is on the client side and how it is received on the server side. I inspected the client side from the requests content from browser how it is sent. It is keeping it the way it is. The transformation happens on the backeden.